# Local domain email configuration for two SharePoint 2007 email enabled document libraries

Tags: email, sharepoint, smtp, document-library

I have a virtual SharePoint 2007 environment, comprising of a domain controller, SQL server and application server (3 VM instances). The domain name is `contoso.local`. I need to email-enable two SharePoint document libraries and thereby created two separate domain user accounts - `userA` and `userB`. My understanding is that if I need to send and receive email within this environment via SharePoint, I must set up SMTP service on the SharePoint installed server whose hostname is `MOSS2007`. So I installed the SMTP Windows component and set up a default virtual SMTP server. After doing these, I see `moss2007.contoso.local` and `contoso.local` under domains. The drop directory of the former is `C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Drop`.

When I started Outlook Express the first time on the SharePoint server, it prompted me to set up a user. I set one up for `userA` and specified an email address of `usera@moss2007.contoso.local`. This ended up creating a folder at `c:\Inetpub\mailroot\Mailbox\contoso.local\P3_UserA.mbx`. When some SharePoint event receiver code sends an email to `UserA@moss2007.contoso.local`, the mail file appears in this folder, instead of `C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Drop`. My Outlook client is able to read this message, but the SharePoint email enabled document library is unable to receive and add this email to the document library, because it must be monitoring only the drop folder.

How do I set this up correctly, so the SharePoint email enabled document libraries corresponding to `UserA` and `UserB` correctly monitor and receive the correct emails respectively?

Comment: Have you looked at the step by step configuration guide on MSDN https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263260.aspx Is it the same as the steps you did?

Comment: I cant help you when you don't give me feedback.

Comment: @STORM it appears that setting up mailboxes in POP3 service was creating a separate folder structure under C:\Inetpub\mailroot, and SharePoint was looking only in the Drop folder. Once I deleted those mailboxes, mail got dropped into the Drop folder and SharePoint started picking it up. The articles you pointed to did not directly address the issue I was facing.

Comment: @STORM there is no way for me to award the bounty to you. If you think you can provide an answer that specifically addresses my question and takes my recent comment into account, I will be happy to award the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the POP3 configuration of the IIS POP3 service you can define a folder where the folder structure will be created under.

[image]

For each user there will be also created a subdirectory named `username.mbx`. Like

c:\inetpub\mailroot\mailbox\domain\username.mbx...

But SharePoint will only look into the rootfolder like `c:\inetpub\mailroot\`.

You need to delete those mailboxes to get it work. See also this MSDN post [Incoming email problem: mail in Drop and mailbox folder but not in list](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1e6cf316-ca56-4d9e-a778-938deca5b283/incoming-email-problem-mail-in-drop-and-mailbox-folder-but-not-in-list?forum=sharepointadminlegacy) on this issue.